# Dynamic CSS classes and rules in a VueJS component depending on a table in a database

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a table "css_rules" with 2 columns: "id_type" and "icone_type".
I'd like to generate CSS rules like this:

```
.custom-marker .[id_type] {
  background-image: url(http://example.com/[icone_type].svg);
}
```

What I tried is that:

```
async setup(props, { emit }) {
const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL;
const cssRules = reactive({});

const cssText = computed(() => {
  let result = '';

  for (const key in cssRules) {
    result += `.custom-marker .${key} {`;
    const rules = cssRules[key];
    for (const property in rules) {
      result += `${property}: ${rules[property]};`;
    }
    result += '}';
  }

  return result;
});

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetch(`${apiUrl}/referentiels/lister/typesressource`, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
  })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((r) => {
      r.forEach((type) => {
        cssRules[type.id_type] = {
          backgroundImage: `url(http://example.com/${type.icone_type}.svg) !important`,
        };
      });
    });
});
return {
  cssText,
};
```

},

And in the template:

```html
<template>
  <div id="map">XXX</div>
    {{ cssText }}
    
  <style>
    {{ cssText }}
  </style>
</template>
```

The fact is that the "cssText" text displays perfectly, but I have an error:

> [plugin:vite:vue] Tags with side effect ( and ) are ignored in client component templates.

Apparently I can't create my own `style` tag inside my component. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way in Vue to dynamically add or remove CSS classes. But you can do it in regular JS, by creating a style tag and adding it to the HTML head:

```
const registerStyles = (id, stylesString) => {
  let styleEl = document.getElementById(id)
  if (!styleEl) {
    const el = document.createElement('style')
    el.type = 'text/css'
    el.id = id
    styleEl = el
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl)
  }
  styleEl.innerHTML = stylesString
}
```

Here it is in a small snippet:

```js
const { createApp, watch, ref } = Vue;

const colors = ['purple', 'hotpink', 'darkviolet']
const classes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

const buildStyles = () => classes.map(className => {
    const colorIx = Math.random() * colors.length | 0
    const color = colors[colorIx]
    return `.${className}{ background: ${color}; }`
  }).join("\n")

const registerStyles = (id, stylesString) => {
  let styleEl = document.getElementById(id)
  if (!styleEl) {
    const el = document.createElement('style')
    el.type = 'text/css'
    el.id = id
    styleEl = el
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl)
  }
  styleEl.innerHTML = stylesString
}

  
const App = {
  setup(){
    const rebuildStyles = () => {
      const styles = buildStyles()
      registerStyles('mystyles', styles)
    }
    rebuildStyles()
    return {
      rebuildStyles
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
  <div class="baz">baz</div>
  <button @click="rebuildStyles">rebuild styles</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Have a look at [how Vuetify does it](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/next/packages/vuetify/src/composables/theme.ts#L306-L346), they use a library for document head management ([`@vueuse/head`](https://github.com/vueuse/head)), and use DOM manipulation (as above) as fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to dynamically assign the image URL, I recommend using [style binding](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind). With this, you can create an object that contains CSS properties in camel case and assign it to the `style` prop. Observe:

```js
<script setup>
const buildStyle = (skill) => {
  const image = skill.toLowerCase();
  
  return {
    backgroundImage: `url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/${image}/${image}-original.svg")`,
    width: '18px',
    height: '18px',
  };
};

const skills = ['VueJS', 'React'];
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <article v-for="skill in skills" :key="skill">
      <div :style="buildStyle(skill)" />
      {{ skill }}
    </article>
  </main>
</template>
```

[Live Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdUd9LwzAQ/leOIHSDrcE3qd1AfFJ8cuCLEZY1sY3L0pCknaP0fzdp0ik+HNyv77677wb0oHXedxwVqLSVEdqB5a7TW6KqVlkHh05ItnMXyWEDC3sUUi5hs4WBKIDYIk60DtWpmLv2pT1z80gtXyzvQ1cw44caFVEAB1oda9N2ij0FbAH7zsgFQY1z2hYYV0zlX5ZxKXqTK+5w3WDGexH4ZgfH6GaY6Mers26NqIWiMrd9TdByv4qcZ8FcUwBBt3f6m6CUbbioG/cvPfq1g80aTIdZf+F79tbx5122guyV08plH76rxFE4L5kPHD9pSR33EUB5okJNnvepcaLyMvbrz9ZsCJqmglBpPEFQHPllLhCUcB7JRA+FDT/w1d+HpG94IL72DkMcB+OYaHHijQvhtFGJ/yyKxh9k6a6c)